# update table value while iterating

Tags: lua, lua-table

i'm currently learning LUA. My question is how to change the value in a table, i got nil:

my table is:

```
local players = {
  {name = something, count = 1}
}

for _, current in ipairs(players) do
    if current.name == inflictor.name then
        local count = players[current].count   --NIL
        players[current].count = count + 1
        break
    end
end
```

thanks for the help

Comment: indexing `players` is unnecessary just use `current.count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ipairs` loop, `_` is the key and `current` is the value, which in this case is that table inside your `players` table.

You'd fix that if you set either:
`players[_].count` or just `current.count`